# PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am running the following firebase code

```
    FirebaseApp app = await FirebaseApp.configure(
          name: 'weather app',
          options: const FirebaseOptions(
            googleAppID: '1:nnnnnnnnn:android:nnnnnnn',
            apiKey: 'XXXXXXXX',
            projectID: 'XXXXX-XXX-XXX08',
          ),
        );
        Firestore firestore = Firestore(app: app);
        FirebaseAuth.fromApp(app).signInAnonymously();
```

if I run this code for the first time in the emulator, it is throwing the following error

```
 I/flutter (17766): getConfigState ERROR 2 PlatformException(Error performing get, PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions., null)
W/Firestore(17766): (21.3.0) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(weather-api-info/owm) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
```

But if I simply reload the app using hot reload or full reload then it doesn't complain. Again, the issue is occuring only when the app runs for the first time on the device (i can re-produce this by uninstalling the app and trying again)

**Cloud firestore auth look like below(I am not planning to set up any sign-in or auth, but don't want to keep it open as well**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your security rules require that a user be signed in at the time of the query.

Comment: That @DougStevenson , is there way i can keep the access closed and yet not have the sign-in, or how to sign in as the admin..? also, why does the same code run the second time without complaining ?

Comment: There is no way to restrict Firestore queries to just your app.  You have to use Firebase Auth to restrict access.

Comment: @KenWhite just did, hit the save button, too soon…

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks, however, if I just reload the code the second time using hotreload, same code works..**output** `I/flutter (17766): getConfigState from firebase https://community-open-weather-map.p.rapidapi.com/weather/`

Comment: The anonymous signin probably finally completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I was able to fix this myself. In a nutshell, I did not set up the code properly for async calls. 
Following is what I modified (compare the code mentioned below to the one in the original post)

```
Future<void> getOWMFirestoreData() async {
  try {
    FirebaseApp app = await FirebaseApp.configure(
      name: 'weather app',
      options: const FirebaseOptions(
            googleAppID: '1:nnnnnnnnn:android:nnnnnnn',
            apiKey: 'XXXXXXXX',
            projectID: 'XXXXX-XXX-XXX08',
      ),
    );
    await FirebaseAuth.fromApp(app).signInAnonymously();
    Firestore firestore = Firestore(app: app);

    var docs =
        await firestore.collection('XXX-info').document('owm').get();
    debugPrint('getOWMFirestoreData Succesfull ${docs.exists}');
```